# How to set the value of an element in JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I currently reside with a problem where I need to pass a value to a Jquery UI Dialog, but I have no idea how. I have checked around for documentation everywhere, but nothing seems to work. This is what I have (and have tried)

Actual Dialog:

```
    <div id="amountDialog" title="Add to Basket">
        <table style="text-align: center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <p id="productAdd"></p> <!-- need to set this value -->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="modalInputAmount" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="maxAmt">Maximum Amount: </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Dialog Options:

```
$( "#amountDialog" ).dialog({ 
                        autoOpen: false, 
                        width: 'auto',
                        modal: true,
                        buttons : {
                            "OK" : execute
                        },
                        open : function (event, ui) {
                            $("#productAdd").val('How many [' + item + ']\'s do you wish to add to the basket?"'); <!-- item is the global variable describing which item is added to the basket -->
                        }
                    });
```

Opening code

```
    $("#amountDialog" ).dialog("open");
```

I won't bother pasting the execute code here as I know that works, I can get the value from the textbox in the modal dialog. My concern however is, how do I set the value of the `#productAdd` paragraph when the modal dialog opens?

Just need to put this out there again, I am still a newbie with JQuery.

Comment: I am positive it returned a value. the button opening the dialog is nested between a table > tbody > tr > td (it is a dynamic button). so this (the button). parent (td) . parent (tr) . nth-child(1)  therefore gets the first column's value in the row the button is in

Comment: or not. just saw the bug haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be `html()` not `val()`, change:

```
$("#productAdd").val(...)
```

to

```
$("#productAdd").html(...);
```

Comment: This worked. thanks. Will Set as correct answer in a few mins

Comment: 1 more question though, how do I know when to use val, and when to use html? 

from all the code snippets I have seen, this is starting to confuse me

Comment: @EonRustedduPlessis The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea... , see more in jquery docs :: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: `.val()` for form elements.`.html()` and `.text()` are used to get or set innerHTML and innerText respectively of nodes rather than form nodes e.g. DIV

Comment: thanks guys. I need all the help I can get. I feel ashamed that this is a job-interview assessment which I am screwing up like this :P all in the spirit to grow and get a salary ^_^

Comment: @EonRustedduPlessis ;) and also Sudhir +1.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that `#productAdd` is a paragraph (`<p>`). jQuery's `val()` method applies only to form fields. Use `html` or `text` instead. E.g. `$('#productAdd').text("How many ...")`

On a side note, you want to reconsider how you're determining `#productAdd`'s new content. The `parent().parent().find('specific thing')` you have now means your script will break as soon as the HTML is changed.